# Deleting data from the middle of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 table which has a column that stores a pathname for note purpose only. The column is called `DESCRIPTION` and looks a little like this:

```
X1200/Redbridge_2/edf0192
```

I have to delete the middle part of the above (the `/Redbridge_2` part in this example, although the names are different throughout). However, I only want to do this for records starting `X1200`. I can't find how to run a query in SQL Server 2008 R2 to delete only the data after the initial `/`, and only up to the second `/`. I would really appreciate any help.

The table name is `PAR`, by the way.

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL String functions?  In particular PATINDEX and SUBSTRING?

Comment: I'm sorry, not really. I am quite new to SQL (only been using it since October).

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of string functions I think this query will do what you want:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET DESCRIPTION = LEFT(DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('/',DESCRIPTION,0)) + SUBSTRING(DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('/',DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('/',DESCRIPTION,0)+1), LEN(DESCRIPTION))
WHERE LEFT(description, 5) = 'X1200'
```

This would change your sample string to `X1200//edf0192`.

There might be better ways to do it. If you want to see what the rows look like before you apply the update you can run it as a select statement:

```
SELECT LEFT(DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('/',DESCRIPTION,0)) + SUBSTRING(DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('/',DESCRIPTION, CHARINDEX('/',DESCRIPTION,0)+1), LEN(DESCRIPTION))
FROM your_table
WHERE LEFT(description, 5) = 'X1200'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. I'll try that now.